# Xst:3002 in Verilog

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I'm creating a downcounter on ISE 14.7.
I set an asynchronous reset(rst_n), whenever it turns 0, the value of counter will be set to init_value.

But as I syntheize the code, 
there appears a warning: Xst3002

Code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module downcounter(value, borrow, clk, rst_n, decrease, init_value, limit);
    output reg [3:0]value;              //value of counter
    output reg borrow;                  //borrow indicator
    input clk, rst_n, decrease;         //clock; active low reset; to decrease
    input [3:0]init_value, limit;       //initial value; counter limit

    reg [3:0]value_tmp, init_value_tmp; //for always block

    //Combinational logic
    always @(value or decrease or limit or borrow)begin
        if(~decrease) begin value_tmp = value; borrow = 0; end      //if decrease is 0, the counter stops counting down.
        else begin
            if(value == 0)begin value_tmp = limit; borrow = 1; end  //if the value is 0, the next value would be the limit.
            else begin value_tmp = value + 4'b1111; borrow = 0; end //Ex: limit = 9, so that value(now) = 0, then value(next) = 9 in decimal.
        end
    end
    //Sequentical logic
    always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
        if(~rst_n) value <= init_value_tmp;             //asynchronous reset. set the value to initial value
        else begin
            value <= value_tmp;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

and the message of warning:

> WARNING:Xst:3002 - This design contains one or more registers/latches
>   that are directly    incompatible with the Spartan6 architecture. The
>   two primary causes of this is    either a register or latch described
>   with both an asynchronous set and    asynchronous reset, or a register
>   or latch described with an asynchronous    set or reset which however
>   has an initialization value of the opposite     polarity (i.e.
>   asynchronous reset with an initialization value of 1).
>       While this circuit can be built, it creates a sub-optimal implementation    in terms of area, power and performance. For a more
>   optimal implementation    Xilinx highly recommends one of the
>   following:
>
> ```
>       1) Remove either the set or reset from all registers and latches
>          if not needed for required functionality
>       2) Modify the code in order to produce a synchronous set
>          and/or reset (both is preferred)
>       3) Ensure all registers have the same initialization value as the
>          described asynchronous set or reset polarity
>       4) Use the -async_to_sync option to transform the asynchronous
>          set/reset to synchronous operation
>          (timing simulation highly recommended when using this option)
> ```
>
> Please refer to http://www.xilinx.com search string "Spartan6
>   asynchronous set/reset" for more details.
>
> List of register instances with asynchronous set and reset:
>       value_0 in unit 
>       value_1 in unit 
>       value_2 in unit 
>       value_3 in unit

it seems that the warning appears because of [3:0]value. But I have no idea about it.
I've tried to change the asynchronous reset to 0, the warning disappeared.
But that isn't what I want.

Comment: Just a side thought. You should drive some value to `borrow ` upon reset.

Comment: please update code with comments what you want actually and what is the possible behavior of your circuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here with this design. First of all, `init_value_tmp` doesn't seem to have a value set. Second, as it is a non-constant, the Spartan-6 architecture may be unable to actually reset to that value using the built-in reset functionality. Change `value <= init_value_tmp;` so that it assigns some meaningful constant to `value`.

As for the async reset, it appears to be valid, but as I do not own a Spartan-6 device, you'd have to synthesize it and try for yourself. My concern is that whatever constant value you use might run into the polarity warning you got before. It's likely that a synchronous reset would "just work" as it's simply a mux in the CLB going into the data input.

**Edit:** In regard to your goal of using a non-constant reset value, you'd almost necessarily need a synchronous reset (which is more of an assignment than a reset):

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(~rst_n) value <= init_value_tmp;
    else begin
        value <= value_tmp;
    end
end
```

Comment: I've tried to change `value <= init_value_tmp;` and added `initial begin init_value_tmp = init_value; end`  above. But the warning still appeared.

Comment: So I can't use a non-constant to be a reset value?

Comment: @JackyHuang Not asynchronously. Synchronously, it can be done very easily. The non-constant is multiplexed into the input of the flip-flop, which is fairly easy in most FPGA architectures. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I want to know why I can't use an asynchronous reset. Is it related to the architecture? Or just regard it as an assignment?

Comment: @JackyHuang Somewhat both. Typically, an async reset has a special implementation at the silicon level, and may only be able to be reset to a value that's fixed in the FPGA bitstream. I am double-checking the Spartan-6 CLB user guide for more details right now.

Comment: I appreciate your time and effort. :) very grateful . I will check the user guide by myself, too.

Comment: Whatever the implementation, you should avoid asynchronously resetting to a non-constant value. Doing so requires logic driving the asynchronous set/reset inputs to flip-flops. This is not _synchronous design_ and should for that reason be avoided.